# PlayerPrefs.SetInt and .GetInt having undesired effect

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, save

Pretty much I have an app in Unity3D which I'm making for android, and you can collect coin which are the currency for the game. Every time I start the game, my coin amount is initialised to 0 even though I am using setInt and getInt to try and save the coin amount for the next time a player plays the game.

Totally unsure why it's not saving the coinAmount, any ideas? (Probably something stupid because I'm a bit of a noob).

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class pickupCoin : MonoBehaviour {

public int amountOfCoins;
public AudioClip coinPing;
public AudioSource playerAudio;

void Start () {


    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalCoinsPlayerPrefs") == null){

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TotalCoinsPlayerPrefs", 0);
    }

    amountOfCoins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalCoinsPlayerPrefs");

}


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other){

    if(other.gameObject.name.Contains("coin")){

        playerAudio.PlayOneShot(coinPing);

        amountOfCoins+=1;

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TotalCoinsPlayerPrefs", amountOfCoins);

        Debug.Log("amount of coins is: " + amountOfCoins);

        Debug.Log("Player Prefs Coin Amount Is" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalCoinsPlayerPrefs").ToString());

        Destroy(other.gameObject);



    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your Start function should look like this.

```
void Start () {

    amountOfCoins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalCoinsPlayerPrefs"); // handles case it doesn't exist and provides a default value of zero unless otherwise specified

}
```

I just verified that you don't have to call `PlayerPrefs.Save()`.

Can you verify that this script works for you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerPrefsScript : MonoBehaviour {

public int amountOfCoins;

void Start () {
    amountOfCoins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalCoinsPlayerPrefs");
}

void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (0, 0, 100, 50), "Coins: " + amountOfCoins)) {
        amountOfCoins++;    
    }
}

void OnDestroy(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("TotalCoinsPlayerPrefs", amountOfCoins);
}

}
```

Comment: Hey Nunery thanks for the comment. I am not calling PlayerPrefs.Save() but I am using playerprefs for my highscore and that seems to be working fine with similar code so I'm a bit confused

Comment: @BarneyChambers +1 for `PlayerPrefs.Save`: "By default Unity writes preferences to disk on Application Quit. In case when the game crashes or otherwise prematurely exits, you might want to write the PlayerPrefs at sensible 'checkpoints' in your game. This function will write to disk potentially causing a small hiccup, therefore it is not recommended to call during actual gameplay." http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html Do Android games actually ever "quit"?

Comment: I just changed my code to that, and also called PlayerPrefs.Save() and still nothing :/. When I debug.log the playerPrefs.GetInt("TotalCoinsPlayerPrefs") it shows that it picks up a coin and the value is 1, but when I reset the game (pressing the play button twice) it's reset to 0 again

Comment: Did you try the modified `Start()` function?

Answer (score 2):

The test that you're using to check the PlayerPref existence (`PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalCoinsPlayerPrefs") == null`) is "wrong". The correct way for that task is to invoke the [HasKey](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.HasKey.html) function.

Basically, I think that your current test always returns TRUE, and your PlayerPref's content is always initialized to `0` as the game starts.

Comment: nope, it will never return true, because [GetInt](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetInt.html) will always return a default value. If you don't specify it, it defaults to 0.